# Ways for developing an in house app (just for members of an enterprise)

Tags: iphone, development, enterprise

I wanna develop a private app for just some members of a small enterprise. Can somebody give me an hint for further readings in this topic?

Comment: There +1 for not commented down votes

Comment: @killswitch, I have a feeling whoever downvoted feels that this question lacks research effort, and/or perhaps is not useful/unclear. Google reveals over 11K results in this field and Apple has [their own page](http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/). Note that it isn't a requirement to comment on downvoting (and I don't believe it's even recommended) just like it isn't a requirement on upvoting. Hope that helps explain (I didn't downvote).

Comment: A similar question has been asked on Stack Overflow earlier: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104922/how-to-restrict-application-distribution-to-a-group-of-users-only-via-apple-apps

Comment: I have no problems with down votes but it is best to comment as to why the post is being down voted !!

Comment: I know it's unspecific, sorry. I found this link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ which might be the solution. If i sign it with this certificate as i read, is it possible to distribute it to everybody in the company without making any registration of the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific liesence for enterprises which you can use and distribute the app locally, for further details check https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/